# AngularJS - $http missed specific key from request Payload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, request, payload

I'm using angular 1.5.7, and no idea why It's missing that key. Frequency of that bug is really low.

Server side rarely get post Request Payload without "priceMin":

expected:

```
{priceMin: 0, priceMax: 964, category: "", name: ""}
```

what I've get:

```
{priceMax: 964, category: "", name: ""}
```

```js
function _doRequestPOST(request_url, data) {
        var def = $q.defer(),
            request = {
                headers: {
                    'X-Requested-With' :'XMLHttpRequest'
                },
                method  : 'POST',
                url     : request_url,
                data    : data
            };

        http = $http(request).then(
            function(response){
                //success
                def.resolve(response);
            },
            function(response){
                //error
                def.reject(response);
            }
        );
        delete http;
        return def.promise;
    };

this.sendStats = function(){
        var requestData = {
                priceMin: self.priceRange.min,
                priceMax: self.priceRange.max,
                category: self.filterExterior,
                name: self.searchBot.name
            };
        _doRequestPOST('/saveFilterData', requestData);
        }
    };
```

Comment: Is `self.priceRange.min` defined and not null in these requests?

Comment: It is defined and not null